# High Quality Image Scaling Library

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, image-manipulation, image-scaling

I want to scale an image in C# with quality level as good as Photoshop does. Is there any C# image processing library available to do this thing?

Comment: This is in C#, that other question is C++, so it's not a duplicate at all.

Comment: The http://imageresizing.net/ library offers the highest-quality and highest-performance image resizing you can get. The accepted answer falls victim [to one of the many GDI+ pitfalls](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/) and will cause a 1px wide border artifact around each image it generates. That's fixed by using an ImageAttributes instance with TileModeXY set for the last parameter to the DrawImage call.

Comment: @Computer Linguist -- is TileModeXY a typo?  You have copy pasted this comment across several answers and a google search for exactly "TileModeXY" only turns up your posts.

The following link for System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode only shows 5 possible values: Tile, TileFlipX, TileFlipY, TileFlipXY, Clamp

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.wrapmode.aspx

Comment: Yes, it should be TileFlipXY, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Here's a nicely commented Image Manipulation helper class that you can look at and use.  I wrote it as an example of how to perform certain image manipulation tasks in C#.  You'll be interested in the **ResizeImage** function that takes a System.Drawing.Image, the width and the height as the arguments.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace DoctaJonez.Drawing.Imaging
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides various image untilities, such as high quality resizing and the ability to save a JPEG.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ImageUtilities
    {    
        /// <summary>
        /// A quick lookup for getting image encoders
        /// </summary>
        private static Dictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo> encoders = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// A lock to prevent concurrency issues loading the encoders.
        /// </summary>
        private static object encodersLock = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// A quick lookup for getting image encoders
        /// </summary>
        public static Dictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo> Encoders
        {
            //get accessor that creates the dictionary on demand
            get
            {
                //if the quick lookup isn't initialised, initialise it
                if (encoders == null)
                {
                    //protect against concurrency issues
                    lock (encodersLock)
                    {
                        //check again, we might not have been the first person to acquire the lock (see the double checked lock pattern)
                        if (encoders == null)
                        {
                            encoders = new Dictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo>();

                            //get all the codecs
                            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
                            {
                                //add each codec to the quick lookup
                                encoders.Add(codec.MimeType.ToLower(), codec);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //return the lookup
                return encoders;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Resize the image to the specified width and height.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="image">The image to resize.</param>
        /// <param name="width">The width to resize to.</param>
        /// <param name="height">The height to resize to.</param>
        /// <returns>The resized image.</returns>
        public static System.Drawing.Bitmap ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int width, int height)
        {
            //a holder for the result
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
            //set the resolutions the same to avoid cropping due to resolution differences
            result.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

            //use a graphics object to draw the resized image into the bitmap
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                //set the resize quality modes to high quality
                graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                //draw the image into the target bitmap
                graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
            }

            //return the resulting bitmap
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Saves an image as a jpeg image, with the given quality 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="path">Path to which the image would be saved.</param> 
        /// <param name="quality">An integer from 0 to 100, with 100 being the 
        /// highest quality</param> 
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        /// An invalid value was entered for image quality.
        /// </exception>
        public static void SaveJpeg(string path, Image image, int quality)
        {
            //ensure the quality is within the correct range
            if ((quality < 0) || (quality > 100))
            {
                //create the error message
                string error = string.Format("Jpeg image quality must be between 0 and 100, with 100 being the highest quality.  A value of {0} was specified.", quality);
                //throw a helpful exception
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(error);
            }

            //create an encoder parameter for the image quality
            EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
            //get the jpeg codec
            ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

            //create a collection of all parameters that we will pass to the encoder
            EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            //set the quality parameter for the codec
            encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
            //save the image using the codec and the parameters
            image.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Returns the image codec with the given mime type 
        /// </summary> 
        public static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
        {
            //do a case insensitive search for the mime type
            string lookupKey = mimeType.ToLower();

            //the codec to return, default to null
            ImageCodecInfo foundCodec = null;

            //if we have the encoder, get it to return
            if (Encoders.ContainsKey(lookupKey))
            {
                //pull the codec from the lookup
                foundCodec = Encoders[lookupKey];
            }

            return foundCodec;
        } 
    }
}
```

---

## Update

A few people have been asking in the comments for samples of how to consume the ImageUtilities class, so here you go.

```
//resize the image to the specified height and width
using (var resized = ImageUtilities.ResizeImage(image, 50, 100))
{
    //save the resized image as a jpeg with a quality of 90
    ImageUtilities.SaveJpeg(@"C:\myimage.jpeg", resized, 90);
}
```

### Note

Remember that images are disposable, so you need to assign the result of your resize to a using declaration (or you could use a try finally and make sure you call dispose in your finally).

Comment: ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = getEncoderInfo("image/jpeg"); - where did you define getEncoderInfo cause I can't compile it

Comment: It should read GetEncoderInfo and not getEncoderInfo. I fixed the typo and the class compiles now.

Comment: How to use this code to show thumbnail on fly (without saving thumbnail to a file)?

Comment: Use the ResizeImage function, it returns the resized image as a System.Drawing.Bitmap object that you can use.

Comment: +1 this works brilliantly! One issue you need to correct in this code is to convert the quality variable to a long prior to passing it to the encoder param or you will get a invalid parameter runtime exception.

Comment: Add `result.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);` to make sure you don't run into weird differences between the source image's resolution and the default bitmap resolution.

Comment: The `Encoders` property is not thread safe, but could pretty easily be made so by using double-checked locking (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

Comment: @DoctorJones When I re-size an image with 300*308 dimensions and 16KB size to an image with 150*120 dimensions, the re-sized image that is smaller than original one has a bigger size, its size is 30KB! I have changed the three re-sized method properties to the lowest, but no difference

Comment: @Behzad are you saving the image as a jpeg?  If so you need to set the quality parameter.  I'd presume that your original image was encoded at a lower quality than what you're trying to save as now.

Comment: @DoctorJones, so, if the original picture is encoded at a lower quality, what should I do to re-size it with that quality? Thanks :)

Comment: @Behzad, if you look, the SaveJpeg function takes an int parameter called quality.  You need to call that and specify the correct value for the quality parameter (it accepts a value between 0 and 100).

Comment: @DoctorJones, Thanks a lot. If the file isn't Jpeg file, I should save it with the default Image.save method without format parameter?

Comment: IT would be great to have the complete & final code also posted so to help others as i am also struggling with similar issue.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker I've added some example usage that will hopefully help

Comment: This solution produces ghost-borders. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1890605/65387) for solution.

Comment: Recommend incorporating one of these concurrency changes into this answer in order to prevent concurrency issues I ran into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068294/what-would-cause-this-property-to-occasionally-throw-a-nullreferenceexception/35068626#35068626

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for the comment. I've added concurrency protection as per your request.  I've used a double check lock pattern instead of Lazy, to maintain compatibility with earlier versions of the framework.

Comment: what about `graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;`  is it not use full ?

Comment: After a long search, this answer's sizing part (_didn't use whole code_) worked for qrcode resizing without quality lost. Right settings are important for result quality.

Answer (score 15):

When you draw the image using GDI+ it scales quite well in my opinion. You can use this to create a scaled image.

If you want to scale your image with GDI+ you can do something like this:

```
Bitmap original = ...
Bitmap scaled = new Bitmap(new Size(original.Width * 4, original.Height * 4));
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(scaled)) {
  graphics.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, scaled.Width, scaled.Height));
}
```

Comment: Not sure if code has changed, but I had to omit the `new Size` in the declaration of `scaled`: `new Bitmap(original.Width * 4, original.Height * 4);`

Answer (score 10):

Tested libraries like [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) and [GD](http://gd-sharp.sourceforge.net/) are available for .NET

You could also read up on things like bicubic interpolation and write your own.

Answer (score 8):

CodeProject articles discussing and sharing source code for **scaling images:**

- [Two Pass Scaling using **Filters**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/2_pass_scaling.aspx)
- [Matrix Transformation of Images in C#, using **.NET GDI+**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/matrix_transformation.aspx)
- [Resizing a Photographic image with **GDI+ for .NET**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageresize.aspx)
- [Fast Dyadic Image Scaling with **Haar Transform**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/Dyadic_down_sampling.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Use this library: http://imageresizing.net

Have a read of this article by the library author: [20 Image Sizing Pitfalls with .NET](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/)

Answer (score 4):

Try the different values for Graphics.InterpolationMode. There are several typical scaling algorithms available in GDI+. If one of these is sufficient for your need, you can go this route instead of relying on an external library.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [dotImage](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/), one of my company's products, which includes an [object for resampling](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/docs/Atalasoft.dotImage~Atalasoft.Imaging.ImageProcessing.ResampleCommand_members.html) images that has [18 filter types](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/docs/Atalasoft.dotImage~Atalasoft.Imaging.ImageProcessing.ResampleMethod.html) for various levels of quality.

Typical usage is:

```
// BiCubic is one technique available in PhotoShop
ResampleCommand resampler = new ResampleCommand(newSize, ResampleMethod.BiCubic);
AtalaImage newImage = resampler.Apply(oldImage).Image;
```

in addition, dotImage includes 140 some odd image processing commands including many filters similar to those in PhotoShop, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: The SDK with this feature is now available for free for common photo formats (JPEG, PNG, etc) http://www.atalasoft.com/photofree

Comment: /Lou Franco: can the common format free version be used in production deployments, also for free?

Comment: Yes, DotImage Photo Free is free to deploy.

Answer (score 2):

This might help

```
    public Image ResizeImage(Image source, RectangleF destinationBounds)
    {
        RectangleF sourceBounds = new RectangleF(0.0f,0.0f,(float)source.Width, (float)source.Height);
        RectangleF scaleBounds = new RectangleF();

        Image destinationImage = new Bitmap((int)destinationBounds.Width, (int)destinationBounds.Height);
        Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(destinationImage);
        graph.InterpolationMode =
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        // Fill with background color
        graph.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White), destinationBounds);

        float resizeRatio, sourceRatio;
        float scaleWidth, scaleHeight;

        sourceRatio = (float)source.Width / (float)source.Height;

        if (sourceRatio >= 1.0f)
        {
            //landscape
            resizeRatio = destinationBounds.Width / sourceBounds.Width;
            scaleWidth = destinationBounds.Width;
            scaleHeight = sourceBounds.Height * resizeRatio;
            float trimValue = destinationBounds.Height - scaleHeight;
            graph.DrawImage(source, 0, (trimValue / 2), destinationBounds.Width, scaleHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            //portrait
            resizeRatio = destinationBounds.Height/sourceBounds.Height;
            scaleWidth = sourceBounds.Width * resizeRatio;
            scaleHeight = destinationBounds.Height;
            float trimValue = destinationBounds.Width - scaleWidth;
            graph.DrawImage(source, (trimValue / 2), 0, scaleWidth, destinationBounds.Height);
        }

        return destinationImage;

    }
```

Note the `InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic` -> this is generally a good tradeoff between performance and results.

Answer (score 1):

Try This basic code snippet:

```
private static Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap srcbmp, int width, int height )
{
    Bitmap newimage = new Bitmap(width, height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newimage))
           g.DrawImage(srcbmp, 0, 0, width, height);
    return newimage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an [article on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imageresize.aspx) about using GDI+ for .NET to do photo resizing using, say, Bicubic interpolation.

There was also another article about this topic on another blog (MS employee, I think), but I can't find the link anywhere. :( Perhaps someone else can find it?

Answer (score 0):

This is an article I spotted being referenced in Paint.NET's code for image resampling: [Various Simple Image Processing Techniques](http://paulbourke.net/texture_colour/imageprocess/) by Paul Bourke.

Comment: 1: Nice article. Couldn't access the link but found this another: http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/texture_colour/imageprocess/

Comment: I corrected the link in the original post as Thomas' link was also broken... http://paulbourke.net/texture_colour/imageprocess/

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained the pertinent parts of the answer, rather than relying on the link.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this one if it's a lowres cgi
[2D Image Filter](http://code.google.com/p/2dimagefilter/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [the magic kernel](http://johncostella.webs.com/magic/). It produces less pixelation artifacts than bicubic resample when upscaling and it also gives very good results when downscaling.
The source code is available in c# from the web site.

Answer (score 0):

I have some improve for Doctor Jones's answer.

It works for who wanted to how to proportional resize the image. It tested and worked for me.

The methods of class I added:

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, Size size)
{
    return ResizeImage(image, size.Width, size.Height);
}


public static Size GetProportionedSize(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, bool withProportion)
{
    if (withProportion)
    {
        double sourceWidth = image.Width;
        double sourceHeight = image.Height;

        if (sourceWidth < maxWidth && sourceHeight < maxHeight)
        {
            maxWidth = (int)sourceWidth;
            maxHeight = (int)sourceHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            double aspect = sourceHeight / sourceWidth;

            if (sourceWidth < sourceHeight)
            {
                maxWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((maxHeight / aspect), 0));
            }
            else
            {
                maxHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((maxWidth * aspect), 0));
            }
        }
    }

    return new Size(maxWidth, maxHeight);
}
```

and new available using according to this codes:

```
using (var resized = ImageUtilities.ResizeImage(image, ImageUtilities.GetProportionedSize(image, 50, 100)))
{
    ImageUtilities.SaveJpeg(@"C:\myimage.jpeg", resized, 90);
}
```