# Cropping images with no loss using .NET

Tags: .net, image, crop

I am trying to understand why after cropping an image in .NET i end up with an image 3 times the size of the original image.
Listed below is the code i am using to crop the image

```
  Private Shared Function CropImage(ByVal img As Image, ByVal cropArea As Rectangle) As Image
      Dim bmpImage As Bitmap = New Bitmap(img)
      Dim bmpCrop As Bitmap = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, img.PixelFormat)
      Return CType(bmpCrop, Image)
   End Function
```

where img is the original image loaded from file into an image object.

How can i achieve a loss less cropping of my image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the second answer to this question:

[High Quality Image Scaling Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249587/high-quality-image-scaling-c)

That code should help.  The problem is that the .NET image handling library defaults the `System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality` setting to 100%, which is literally three times the size of 90%, which has no visible difference in quality.  Use the code in that question to save your image at lower quality settings and you should see a big difference in the size of your file.