# C# Creating thumbnail (low quality and big size problem)

Tags: c#, image, resize, thumbnails

```
public void CreateThumbnail(Image img1, Photo photo, string targetDirectoryThumbs)
        {
            int newWidth = 700;
            int newHeight = 700;
            double ratio = 0;

            if (img1.Width > img1.Height)
            {
                ratio = img1.Width / (double)img1.Height;
                newHeight = (int)(newHeight / ratio);
            }
            else
            {
                ratio = img1.Height / (double)img1.Width;
                newWidth = (int)(newWidth / ratio);
            }

            Image bmp1 = img1.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            bmp1.Save(targetDirectoryThumbs + photo.PhotoID + ".jpg");

            img1.Dispose();
            bmp1.Dispose();
        }
```

I've put `700px` so that you can have better insight of the problem.
Here is [original](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/8614/18full.jpg) image and [resized](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/1825/20458869.png) one.

Any good recommendation?

Thanks,
Ile

Comment: While the extension is "jpg", you are actually saving the bmp1 image in PNG format (the default). To have a Jpeg use bmp1.Save("name", ImageFormat.Jpeg).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should find my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249587/high-quality-image-scaling-c/353222#353222) helpful.  It includes a sample for high quality image scaling in C#.

The full sample in my other answer includes how to save the image as a jpeg.

Here's the relevant bit of code...

```
    /// <summary> 
    /// Resize the image to the specified width and height. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="image">The image to resize.</param> 
    /// <param name="width">The width to resize to.</param> 
    /// <param name="height">The height to resize to.</param> 
    /// <returns>The resized image.</returns> 
    public static System.Drawing.Bitmap ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int width, int height) 
    { 
        //a holder for the result 
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height); 

        //use a graphics object to draw the resized image into the bitmap 
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result)) 
        { 
            //set the resize quality modes to high quality 
            graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality; 
            graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; 
            graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality; 
            //draw the image into the target bitmap 
            graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height); 
        } 

        //return the resulting bitmap 
        return result; 
    }
```

Comment: Ile... One of the important parts of the Docta's answer is :

graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

In your original code every pixel is just moved and made larger without regard for the neighboring pixels....Interpolation, Smoothing and Compositing are key.

Comment: How to save thumbnail as a file? I tried result.Save(targetDirectoryThumbs + photo.PhotoID + ".jpg"); but I get blank image? Thanks!

Comment: ile, take a look at the answer I linked to, there's a function called SaveJpeg that you will find useful.

Comment: You'll need to copy the whole class, it includes the GetEncoderInfo method which you asked about.  It should read GetEncoderInfo and not getEncoderInfo.  I fixed the typo in the other answer.

Comment: You're welcome :-) I'm glad I could help, I remember how happy I was when I got this working.  Have fun manipulating images! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the image contains a thumbnail it'll automatically stretch it to the desired size...which will make it look like crap (like your case ;))

Straight outta MSDN...

> If the Image contains an embedded
>   thumbnail image, this method retrieves
>   the embedded thumbnail and scales it
>   to the requested size. If the Image
>   does not contain an embedded thumbnail
>   image, this method creates a thumbnail
>   image by scaling the main image.

In your case I just double checked the source image for it's thumbnail and got this...

- New Windows Thumbnail : JPEG Format (Offset:830Size:3234)
- Thumbnail Type : JPEG
- Thumnail Width : 112
- Thumbnail Height : 84

Comment: Thanks for the information, I always wondered why this was the case!

Answer (score 1):

Try to draw the original image to another smaller image, and save the result.

```
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawImage(img1, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
bmp1.Save(targetDirectoryThumbs + photo.PhotoID + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use third party applications? If so, you may want to check out ImageMagick to manage thumbnail creation. There's a .NET wrapper.

http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'm allowed to, but I think that built-in solution should do the work (I don't see many complaining :)). Thank you for advise!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a  free .dll that does this easily. It's here if you want to see the documentation....
[Git Repository & Tutorial](http://www.ravennasoftware.com/thumbnail-magic.aspx)