# Displaying an Image from Azure Storage before downloading - C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, picturebox

I'm writing a program that will allow the user to download selected images from Azure Blob Storage.

I have it working, however, currently, the images are downloaded to a file and then this file path is used to display the images. I want the images to be displayed and then allow the user to select which images can be downloaded.

Below is my code for downloading the images.

```
for (int i = 1; i<=dira.ListBlobs().Count(); i++)
{
     try
     {
          CloudBlob blob = dira.GetBlobReference(i + ".png");
          blob.DownloadToFile(localFilePath + "/" + i.ToString() + ".png", FileMode.Create);
          // MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
      }
      catch (StorageException ex)
      {
      }
}
```

Then my code for displaying the downloaded image is here:

```
pictureBox1.BackgroundImage= Image.FromFile(filePath + ".png");
```

How would I display the images before they have been downloaded?

Comment: You may need to upload two version of your images, a full resolution version and a thumbnail version and then use the thumbnail version to display the images to your users before downloading the full one.

Comment: Does the `CloudBLob` give you the url of the image?

Comment: You can't display image without downloading image (or some thumb of image)

Comment: @Haytam not from what I can see.  is there a way without having to download them to a file though? So download them to memory. Display them and then if the images are wanted them download them to file?

Comment: Well if you had the url of the image then you could using `PictureBox.Location` which will download the image but in memory.

Comment: @Haytam I've got the URL so can set it that way now. However, the image is to large. Normally I would set the BackgroundImageLayout to Zoom. How can I still set this property when using a URL?

Comment: Well I guess you can just normally set it? what's the problem

Comment: HI Haytam, I didn't realise I could set it programatically as it wasn't on the designer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said above, we can download them to memory.

Here is simple code for your reference:

```
 CloudBlob blob = dira.GetBlobReference(i + ".png");
 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
 blob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
 pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to really save some network traffic (aka time to download) between PC and Blob storage all you have to do is **create thumbnail in Azure**.

I found a very nice and complete example [how to do that](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/event-grid/resize-images-on-storage-blob-upload-event.md).
Mechanism is pretty neat and 'cloudy'

[image: Thumbnail in cloud]

Please bear in mind, that above could raise your Azure bill. As in other cases in this too you need to consider what are your priorities:

- I need to be super quick and save network for my users -> create thumbnails in Azure
- I want to save costs on my side and performance is not a concern -> download full sized image and create thumbnail on host

Answer (score 0):

> You can not show images without downloading it

**But instead,**

You should create a thumbnail image with your actual image so when you show the list to a user you can download thumbnails from the server and then actual images on user selection

you can create thumbnail using below code

```
    public static System.Drawing.Bitmap ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int width, int height) 
    { 
        //a holder for the result 
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height); 

        //use a graphics object to draw the resized image into the bitmap 
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result)) 
        { 
            //set the resize quality modes to high quality 
            graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality; 
            graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; 
            graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality; 
            //draw the image into the target bitmap 
            graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height); 
        } 

        //return the resulting bitmap 
        return result; 
    }
```

Ref:- [C# Creating thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857806/c-sharp-creating-thumbnail-low-quality-and-big-size-problem)