# video scaling using C#

Tags: c#, video, image-scaling

I need to perform video scaling in my C++ app.  I know I can use COM to communicate to C#, and I know C# can perform video scaling, so I am thinking of bridging the two worlds.

How can I, using C#, scale a video image which is in memory, and then get the video data after the image is scaled?

This question seems similar but how do I get the data after scaling instead of showing it to screen?
[High Quality Image Scaling Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249587/high-quality-image-scaling-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# (using GDI+ a.k.a. `System.Drawing`) can scale individual images, but it has no built-in way of scaling full videos (like MPEGs or AVIs).

Assuming that you actually only need to scale individual images (i.e. not full videos), then you would be better off doing this from C++ (`StretchBlt` would be the main API method that you would use for this.

Comment: +1 with the standard *"or use an existing library"* disclaimer