# asyncfileupload ajax control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using asyncfileupload ajax control and can successfully upload and save picture on server.

I need to do the following and not sure how:

1. When user is in process of uploading, I only want them to see *.jpg *.gif and *.bmp files
2. Once the user uploads their picture, how do I reduce the quality of the picture so it is less than 10 KB?

Env is VS 2008 C#

Thanks,
Behrouz

Answer (score 0):

See here for a perfect answer on scaling and covnerting images: [High Quality Image Scaling Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249587/high-quality-image-scaling-c)

You will have to play with width/height and/or quality until you are below 10k.

René

Comment: Thanks, how about the ability for the user to only see images when choosing files?

Comment: For the allowed extension have a look here: http://programming.top54u.com/post/ASP-Net-FileUpload-File-Type-Filter-using-JavaScript-Validation.aspx