# How can I resize an image in C# while retaining high quality?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, image-resizing

I found an article on image processing from here: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing Everything works fine.

I want to keep the high quality when resizing the image. I think if I can increase the DPI value I can achieve this. Does anyone know if this is possible? And if so, how can I implement it in C#?

Comment: In which direction are you resizing? Is the new image *smaller* or *larger* than the original image?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uoM5kfZIQ0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, it's worth pointing out that there are two general categories of images; vector [e.g. SVG, WMF, Adobe Illustrator and Corel Draw Graphics] and bitmap (also called raster) images [e.g. Bitmap, JPEG and PNG Images].

Vector images are formed from a series of mathematical equations and/or calculations. Bitmap images, on the other hand, are made up of individual dots (pixels) each corresponding to a particular feature on the object the image is taken of.

If it should happen that you want to resize an image, the first thing to consider is if it is a bitmap or vector image. By virtue of the fact that vector images are obtained from calculations, they can be perfectly resized without losing any detail. The case is different for bitmap images. Since each pixel is independent of the other, when you desire to resize it, you are simply increasing or decreasing the source to target pixel ratio.

So in order to double the size of a vector image, simply multiply the target dimensions by two and everything comes out all right. If you should apply the same effect on a bitmap, you are actually increasing each source pixel to cover four pixels (two rows of two horizontal pixels).

Of course, by applying interpolation and filtering, the computer can "smooth" out the edges of the target pixels so they seem to blend into each other and give the appearance of a reasonably resized image but this output is never the same as resizing a vector image; vector images resize perfectly.

You also mentioned **DPI** in your question. DPI is essentially the number of pixels that correspond to an inch when the image is *printed* not when it is *viewed on a screen*. Therefore by increasing the DPI of the image, you do not increase the size of the image on the screen. You only increase the quality of print [which needless to say depends on the maximum resolution of the printer].

If you really desire to resize the image and the image is a bitmap, as a rule of thumb, do not increase the size beyond 200% of the original image's size else you'll lose the quality.

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249587/high-quality-image-scaling-c/353222#353222) for code to resize bitmap images.

To see a sample vector image, go to [this link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/VectorBitmapExample.svg).
**Note** Try zooming in and out of the image to see how well it resizes.

A typical bitmap are the [StackOverflow sprites](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png). They do not keep their quality resized.

**Further Reading**

- Vector Graphics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_image
- Bitmap Graphics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_image

Answer (score 0):

Simply If the original image is smaller then the re-sized image  then there is hardly anything you can do. Rest is a research problem.

Answer (score 0):

This would only be possible if it's a vector graphic. Look into SVG. Otherwise, I think you might need Silverlight or Flex for that part.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking isn't really possible. You can't enlarge an image while maintaining the same quality.
If you think about an image as a mapped array of pixels (literally, a "bit-map"), this makes sense. The image is saved with a fixed amount of data, and that's all you have to work with when you resize it. Any examples to the contrary (like TV shows, as suggested by one of the comments) are purely fictional.

The best that you can do is set the [`InterpolationMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.interpolationmode.aspx) of the `Graphics` object you're using to do the resizing to "HighQualityBicubic", which is the highest quality smoothing algorithm supported by GDI+ and in fact by every major graphics package on the market. It's the best that even Adobe Photoshop has to offer. Essentially, interpolation means that the computer is *calculating* the approximate value of the new pixels you're adding to make the image larger from the relative values of neighboring pixels. It's a "best guess" method, but it's the best compromise we've come up with yet.
At the very least, the resulting images won't have "jaggies" or rough, pixelated lines.

Sample code:

```
Graphics g;
g.InterpolationMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
// ... insert the rest of your code here
```

Beyond that, it's worth noting that GDI+ (which the .NET Framework uses internally for graphics routines) works best with image sizes that are multiples of 16. So if it all possible, you should try and make the width and height of your resized images a multiple of 16. This will preserve as much of the original image quality as possible.

The ideal solution is to switch to vector graphics that can be resized at will. Instead of pixel information, they contain mathematical information used to draw or "render" the image. Read more on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics).

Answer (score 0):

let's try metadata in GDI+, may be it can suit your request