# How to set height of img in c# Code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am try to set img height  which bind in repeater. But i can't :

```
HtmlImage proImg = item.FindControl("proImg") as HtmlImage;
proImg.Attributes.Add("style", "height:407px;");
```

can any one give me solution?

Comment: refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190413/dynamically-change-an-images-height-using-codebehind

Comment: What do you mean by `But i can't`? Is there an error? is the height not set? Is the height wrong? Without some more context we're just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the `ItemDataBound`

```
public void Repeater_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item
    || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)   
  {
    // I'm assuming you are using HTML img tags 
   HtmlImage proImg = e.Item.FindControl("proImg") as HtmlImage;
      proImg.Attributes.Add("style", "height:407px;");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:

```
proImg.Height = 407;
```

Here you have more details about HtmlImage.Height property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/office/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlimage.height(v=vs.71))

Comment: It gives you any error? Or just does not apply the height you set?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use height in Image tag like:

```
<asp:Image Height="407" />
```

This is the simplest way and it saves lot of processing.