# Upscaling a bitmap with no smoothing is inaccurate somehow, how to make it right?

Tags: c#, image, scaling, system.drawing

```
Bitmap outputBitmap = new Bitmap(inputBitmap.Width * 5, inputBitmap.Height * 5);

using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputBitmap))
    {                        
    graphics.CompositingQuality =
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    graphics.InterpolationMode =
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    graphics.SmoothingMode =
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

    graphics.DrawImage(inputBitmap, 0, 0,
        inputBitmap.Width * 5, inputBitmap.Height * 5);
    }
```

The result is an upscaled image offset by a few pixels in direction of top left corner.
[image: what it should look like and what it looks like]

How do I make this right?

Comment: I just tried the exact same thing, but can't see the offset you mention. Here's the entire Program.cs in my test project. http://pastebin.com/2S1Y6F7D

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249587/high-quality-image-scaling-c-sharp ?

Comment: @PeterRitchie nope, not about HQ scaling, just about how it's not even satisfactory by default. First and third parameters can actually be omitted and the result will be the same.