# High quality image scaling

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have read this question, [High Quality Image Scaling Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249587/high-quality-image-scaling-c-sharp) , but it only pertains to GDI+.

When I scale down an `Image` in my app, it becomes very jaggy.

I can't find any property on the `Image` class that allows me to increase the quality of the down-scaling.

How can I do this?

EDIT:

I have now used this code:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img.UriSource = new Uri(Graphic, UriKind.Relative);
return img;
```

where `Graphic` is a `string` that contains the path to the image, but am getting this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Weather.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849 for details.

As far as I know, `Windows.Foundation.Uri` isn't used in the `.net` framework.

So why is it giving me this error?

Comment: Which Image class are you talking about?

Comment: What factor are you downscaling the image?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: @PaoloMoretti My code is basically just an `<Image>` tag that sets a smaller width and height.

Comment: @DoctaJonez [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.aspx)

Comment: I don't think you can do it in XAML. WPF has an attached property [`RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.bitmapscalingmode.aspx) to change the interpolation mode, but this is not available in WinRT. You probably have to create a new scaled image in the code-behind. [This post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/4e49ec9e-db56-4155-a296-91c1ba54d84b) might help you.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti you should add that as an answer

Comment: I guess I just have to ask; why are you down scaling?

Comment: @JerryNixon Because I have large images which need to be displayed as small thumbnails as well as full images.

Answer (score 10):

In XAML:

```
    <Image Width="250" Height="250" Stretch="UniformToFill">
        <Image.Source>
           <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImagePath}" DecodePixelHeight="250"/>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
```

In C#:

```
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = BitmapImage("URL HERE");
    bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 250;
```

Only set DecodePixelHeight or DecodePixelWidth.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelheight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a second, smaller image and using it in all the places where I needed to scale it down.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to avoid the problem you're running into entirely by using the built-in support for image scaling:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx

You can include multiple versions of your images at different resolutions (same filename but either with a known suffix or in a known folder), and the system will automatically load the appropriate one for the DPI of the user's device.