# How to print raw/complex data

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I want to print the contents of a group of different Windows Form controls. I've been reading and printing always rely heavily on WinForms (like capturing the screen or using a RichTextBox) or printing a document file directly (like PDF or word doc)

I want to print this current view. Ideally, the layout should be the same when printed:

<sub>(Click for larger view)</sub>
[image]

How can I print programmatically? Or if that's not the best way to do it, how can I print the above (screenshot) efficiently?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: How can you do _what_ programmatically? If you've been reading, then you know how printing works. What's your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing a Form/UserControl in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165294/printing-a-form-usercontrol-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't that clear. I've been wondering how I can print the data behind a group of different controls. The one I've read relies on RichTextBox or it tries to capture the screen.

Comment: I did this before in visual basic, what I used is crystal reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options - Non is trivial though (may be except #2):

1. Report Generator like Crystal Reports. See here [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1883425.aspx) for Crystal Reports download link and other options. Of course you could opt for a 3rd party tool instead.
2. Generate the data as CSV file and print it from Excel
3. Write text as RTF
4. Generate result as HTML
5. Use MS-Access
6. Other options...

Comment: I tried capturing the UserControls for now. I didn't like it but I was able to print it out.

#2 - seems very viable for me because I don't really need a fancy-looking report.

#1 - I'll take a look at it. Seems promising.

Thanks!