# What would cause this property to occasionally throw a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8.5

I have an asp.net/C# class that resizes images for caching on the server as files, however the portion of the code that determines which encoder to use seems to occasionally throw a NullReferenceException.

Here is the code which initializes and passes back the encoders:

```
public static class ImageUtilities{    
    private static Dictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo> encoders = null;

    public static Dictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo> Encoders{
        get{
            if (encoders == null){
                encoders = new Dictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo>();
            }

            //if there are no codecs, try loading them
            if (encoders.Count == 0){
                foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()){
                    encoders.Add(codec.MimeType.ToLower(), codec);
                }
            }

            return encoders;
        }
    }
    ...
```

This is the specific line the exception is being thrown on:

```
encoders.Add(codec.MimeType.ToLower(), codec);
```

This is the error text:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
```

This is the only place where the Encoders property is called (and subsequently is the line below that one in the stack trace):

```
if (Encoders.ContainsKey(lookupKey)){
    foundCodec = Encoders[lookupKey];
}
```

Even if lookupKey were null, shouldn't the lookup just return null rather than throwing an exception?

Comment: There is a good chance that this code is called from multiple threads (since post includes ASP.NET tag) and hence should be failing that way due to lack of proper synchronization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attempting to use a "lazy loaded singleton", but you're not taking concurrency into account.  The easiest way to do this without sacrificing performance is with `Lazy<T>`:

```
private static Lazy<Dictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo>> _encoders =
    new Lazy<Dictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo>>(() =>
        ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().ToDictionary(x => x.MimeType.ToLower(), x => x));

public static Dictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo> Encoders
{
    get { return _encoders.Value; }
}
```

This is pattern #6 of [Jon Skeet's excellent article on the various ways you can implement this pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

You might also consider using a read-only dictionary, to prevent any callers from trying to add to it.

```
private static Lazy<ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo>> _encoders =
    new Lazy<ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo>>(() =>
        new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo>(
            ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
                .ToDictionary(x => x.MimeType.ToLower(), x => x)));

public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo> Encoders
{
    get { return _encoders.Value; }
}
```

Another way you might handle this is with a `ConcurrentDictionary`, but that seems like overkill since you're not going to be adding items frequently.

Comment: The framework will do it for you with `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: @moarboilerplate - yes, but that's overkill for this scenario.  (Updated my answer right as you were commenting.)

Comment: After looking at the question further you're right--your edit exposing the dictionary as readonly is the best.You can however refactor it--just returning `_encoders.Value` should work

Comment: Yes, but then one can cast it back to a `Dictionary` and add to it.  Encapsulating in a `ReadOnlyDictionary` is a good practice to prevent that.  Though I suppose in this case, it could be done once, during the lazy-load, instead of in the property.  (Either would be acceptable, but updated to use this approach for efficiency.)

Answer (score 1):

Since this code is in ASP.NET app, there may be some issues with concurrency. Try put creating dictionary int `lock` statement:

```
private static object _lock = new object();
public static Dictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo> Encoders{
    get{
       lock(_lock) {
        if (encoders == null){
            encoders = new Dictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo>();
        }

        //if there are no codecs, try loading them
        if (encoders.Count == 0){
            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()){
                encoders.Add(codec.MimeType.ToLower(), codec);
            }
        }

        return encoders;
         }
    }
}
```

Generally `Dictionary` cannot have `null` keys (because the call `GetHashCode()` on every object you put in). But because you call `.ToLower()` on MimeType - it is rather `!= null` (otherwise exception would be throw much earlier). If `lock` doesn't solve the issue you may want to check, what value you actually put into dictionary using debugger.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified since the encoders are not going to change each time you call.  Here is a version that will return the encoders as a dictionary and cache them in your local dictionary object

```
public static Dictionary<string, ImageCodecInfo> Encoders
{
    get {
        return encoders ??
               (encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().ToDictionary(c => c.MimeType.ToLower()));
    }
}
```